# Error running '__rvm_make -j4', in MacOS 11.2.3

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

```
(base) hamidiqbal598@Hamids-MacBook-Pro ~ % \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/archive/1.29.12.tar.gz
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.29.12/1.29.12.tar.gz.asc
gpg: Signature made Fri Jan 15 23:46:22 2021 PKT
gpg:                using RSA key 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
gpg: Good signature from "Piotr Kuczynski <piotr.kuczynski@gmail.com>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 7D2B AF1C F37B 13E2 069D  6956 105B D0E7 3949 9BDB
GPG verified '/Users/hamidiqbal598/.rvm/archives/rvm-1.29.12.tgz'
Upgrading the RVM installation in /Users/hamidiqbal598/.rvm/
    RVM PATH line found in /Users/hamidiqbal598/.mkshrc /Users/hamidiqbal598/.profile /Users/hamidiqbal598/.bashrc /Users/hamidiqbal598/.zshrc.
    RVM sourcing line found in /Users/hamidiqbal598/.profile /Users/hamidiqbal598/.bash_profile /Users/hamidiqbal598/.zlogin.
Upgrade of RVM in /Users/hamidiqbal598/.rvm/ is complete.

Thanks for installing RVM 
Please consider donating to our open collective to help us maintain RVM.

  Donate: https://opencollective.com/rvm/donate


Ruby enVironment Manager 1.29.12 (latest) (c) 2009-2020 Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin

ruby-3.0.0 - #removing src/ruby-3.0.0..
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/11.2/x86_64/ruby-3.0.0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Updating certificates bundle '/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem'
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/hamidiqbal598/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-3.0.0 - #downloading ruby-3.0.0, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-3.0.0 - #extracting ruby-3.0.0 to /Users/hamidiqbal598/.rvm/src/ruby-3.0.0.....
ruby-3.0.0 - #configuring..........................................................................
ruby-3.0.0 - #post-configuration.
ruby-3.0.0 - #compiling.....
Error running '__rvm_make -j4',
please read /Users/hamidiqbal598/.rvm/log/1617288903_ruby-3.0.0/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Comment: Have you read `/Users/hamidiqbal598/.rvm/log/1617288903_ruby-3.0.0/make.log` as indicated in the error output? What did it say?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using big sur OS ?, apparently RMV is well installed, but the problem is at the moment installing ruby 3.0.0, maybe if you run

> CFLAGS="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration" rvm install 3.0.0

or whatever version you want seems to work.

Comment: Still I have the same issue